# Asus mother board Z87 Plus bios don't start

Tags: motherboard

I have a Asus Z87 Plus motherboard.

Yesterday I used my PC and everything worked.

But today the PC don't work. It means when I switch it on the PC fans are running (endlessly) but the screen shows nothing ("There is no signal coming from your computer" says the screen)...

I did not change anything to my pc between yesterday and today..
.
I tried to plug the screen on the integrated DVI motherboard card and on the external DVI graphic card but it changes nothing. And I can confirm that my graphical card are not broken because they work on another PC. My monitors are also not broken because they work with another pc...

Comment: This behavior indicates you have a hardware problem. Its either the CPU or the motherboard.  The resolution problem would only come into play after Windows had been loaded.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah windows don't load and I also don't see anything on the screen. I can't launch the bios... So I also think is the CUP or the motherboard, however do you know how I can solve this issue? How can I know if the issue is my CPU or the motherboard?

Comment: You replace one and hope you picked right.  Unless you have a second motherboard of course.

Comment: AH I see but unfortunately I can't do this at home. So I guess I have to bring my pc in the shop...

Comment: Why pay somebody for something you can do yourself?  The second motherboard can verify if the CPU is working.  If it boots then you know the CPU works and its the motherboard.  If you have another CPU the reverse can be done.  Of course if you have both just replace both and be done with it.

Comment: Yeah but my second motherboard has a different socket model so i can't test like this. But I restarted my computer again and it was working once normally (windows was running) but then I restarted and is not working anymore. I never faced such an issue...

Comment: @Ramhound Finally, I did 2 things: 1 take off the battery for 30min and I pluged off the USB SS Cable. And now is working perfecely good. I still don't know if the problem is the SS Cable or the battery. But is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understand what was the issue. It has nothing to do with the battery.

I just went to the bios and clicked on "default setting" then before to save the bios show me the changes. And the change is related to the voltage that the RAM uses. So everytime I put more or less RAM I have to go to setting and change the default value. After that I can use my PC witouth trouble.

Comment: I'm lost, your OP states you made no changes yet your solution reads as if you did change the RAM

Comment: At the begin I did nothing but then I put RAM out (sometimes with 2 RAM sticks, sometimes 3, etc.) Changed the slots, etc. Then I discovered that if I make a change and put "defaut" value to settings I get some change (voltage) in my bios...

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when it doesn't understand the screen resolution (I had this about 3 weeks ago)! Open the PC up, take the CMOS battery out, leave it out for 2 minutes, put it back in and try. It will then default to the standard settings for the card.

I guess the board could be bust too!

Comment: Hello, thanks for the trick. I did as you told me (took off the battery for 5min)  but unfortunately it changes nothing...

Comment: @Ramhound Finally, I did 2 things: 1 take off the battery for 30min and I pluged off the USB SS Cable. And now is working perfecely good. I still don't know if the problem is the SS Cable or the battery. But is working. – Swiss12000 1 hour ago